# Relax the children constraint in a React class

Tags: reactjs

I have a class `A` that expects all of its children to be of type `B`. I do not control either `A` or `B`, but I want to add `C` which will enhance `B` (add some default attributes, etc).

The current application errors out because `A` expects its children to be `B`, and I am unsure how to make my `C` fit into the picture.

Thank you!

```js
class A extends React.Component {}
class B extends React.Component {}


class Example extends React.Components {
    render() {
        <A>
            <B />
            <B />
            <B />
            <B />
            <C />    <!---- Returns an error -->
        </A>
    }
}

class C extends React.Component {
    render() {
        return (
            <B />
        )
    }
}
```

I am happy to use functional components or any tricks in the library.

Comment: What's the error? What do you mean by "expects its children to be `B`"?

Comment: It's a limitation of the library that I am using (which defined A and B). The error is `warning.js?d96e:34 Warning: A only accept B as children.`

Comment: Does it error or is it just a warning?

Comment: try class C extends B {
  render() {
    return (<div/> );
  }
}

Comment: @rayhatfield, it's a silent error (does not crash but does not render)

Comment: @BabakYaghoobi, then I would have to reimplement my B. I would still want to use the existing B in some way

Comment: Do you have propTypes control on A ?

Comment: Let's assume there is no typecheck required.